# NLTK error: OSError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, anaconda, nltk

I am following the online NLTK book and am trying to execute a line of code the authors have provided as an example (from here: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html; specifically 1.1 Gutenberg Corpus)

```
emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-emma.txt')
```

This throws the error:

```
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 316, in __init__
    raise IOError('No such file or directory: %r' % _path)
```

and

```
OSError: No such file or directory: '/Users/kamila/nltk_data/corpora/gutenberg/austen-emma.text'
```

I followed both of those directories and found they do exist on my computer:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: `.txt` != `.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a format issue(.text vs .txt) as highlighted already. As the below steps work fine in my linux system(see screenshot)

```
import nltk
nltk.download("gutenberg")
emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-emma.txt')
```

[image]